# Why doesn't Electron Builder include the files I mentioned in configuration?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have already added `rsa-cli/node_modules/**/*` to `"files"`, but Electron Builder ignored it. So the required dependencies are missing, RSA CLI throws out an error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '...'`.

`package.json`

```json
{
    ...
    "build": {
        ...
        "files": [
            "LICENSE",
            "main.js",
            "babel.config.json",
            "lib/",
            "rsa-cli/",
            "rsa-cli/node_modules/**/*"
        ]
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've published rsa-cli to npm and installed it to this project as a dependency. So that `node_modules/rsa-cli/` will be packed into the app.